# Dynamic data (month) in email subject and body

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm currently on a project where I need to send an automated email on the first of every month. I created a variable for the Month format.
I need to input the month in the subject and in the mail body. here is my code...

```
function emailnotifications() {
  const currentMonth = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+4", "MMMM");
  GmailApp.sendEmail('test5@gmail.com', 'Monthly report notification'(currentMonth), 'Please note that the monthly report of Stock of (currentMonth) that had been extracted to following folder: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx')
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this `'Monthly report notification'(currentMonth)` to this `'Monthly report notification (' + currentMonth + ')'`

or `` `Monthly report notification (${currentMonth})` `` with the whole string surround with backticks.

Comment: the first one worked like a charm, thank you  ``('+ currentMonth + ')``

Comment: @iansedano thanks for that edit.  I couldn't figure that out